# Why doesn't TypeScript show a type mismatch error here in this example?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I recently started using React with TypeScript, and this is how I defined my types:

```
type CardInfo = {
  cardIndex: null | number;
  title: string;
  note: string;
  _id: string;
  from: string;
  cardId: string;
};

type ContentType = {
  title: string;
  note: string;
  _id: string;
  cardId: string;
};

type ContentForFullScreen = ContentType & {
  cardIndex: number | null;
};

const App: FC = () => { 
  const [cardInfo, setCardInfo] = useState<CardInfo>({
    cardIndex: null,
    title: "",
    note: "",
    _id: "",
    from: "",
    cardId: "",
  });

 const [fullScreenCardData, setFullScreenCardData] =
    useState<ContentForFullScreen>(cardInfo);
}
```

As you can see, the CardInfo type definition has an extra key called **from** which is not present in the ContentForFullScreen type definition. Despite this, when I assign cardInfo to fullScreenCardData using the useState hook:

```
const [fullScreenCardData, setFullScreenCardData]= useState<ContentForFullScreen>(cardInfo);
```

It doesn't show any error. Why is TypeScript not indicating that the key **from** is not present in the type definition of ContentForFullScreen?

But if you add a key that is not present in the cardInfo type definition,
for example:

```
type ContentForFullScreen = ContentType & {
  cardIndex: number | null;
  age: number;
};
```

Here, I have added a key called **age** in the ContentForFullScreen type definition, but it is not present in the cardInfo type definition.

Now, I see an error when attempting:

```
const [fullScreenCardData, setFullScreenCardData]= useState<ContentForFullScreen>(cardInfo);

Argument of type 'cardInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContentForFullScreen | (() => ContentForFullScreen)'.
  Type 'cardInfo' is not assignable to type 'ContentForFullScreen'.
    Property 'age' is missing in type 'cardInfo' but required in type '{ cardIndex: number | null; age: number; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a type definition doesn't exclude objects with additional members. Every key `ContentForFullScreen` requires is present in a `CardInfo` instance, with compatible types.

Comment: So, it means if your object has all the required keys, it's okay to have additional keys that are not defined in the type definition.

Comment: @MaxVhanamane yes